# Defining element type in a table

Tags: lua, roblox

so when i define the type of a variable, it goes totally alright:

```lua
local Player: Player = nil
```

but when i try to define the type of an element in a table, it doesnt go exactly how i thought it would:

```lua
PlayerProfile.Player: Player = nil
```

```
Missed symbol `(`.Luau Syntax Check.(miss-symbol)
```

this is my first time working with `type` so anyone know the correct way of doing this?

Comment: I don't see you define a table element. please add more code. Where did you define type Player?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't arbitrary set type to random table member in Luau. You need to set types for all members on table creation or inside its creation scope.

On creation you can simply set type for each field directly:

```
type PlayerProfile = {Player: SomeType, OtherField: SomeOtherType}
```

Or you can express member types by first creating table with zero expression `{}` and assigning typed values to its members before leaving creation scope. But as soon as you leave that scope the table is "sealed" and no more changes are allowed.

```
local PlayerProfile = {}
PlayerProfile.Player = "string"
PlayerProfile.SomeField = 123 -- number, types are inferred from initialization values
```